# Есть феномен стяжения в русском языке?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Я хотела знать, есть ли в русском языке феномен стяжения, аналогичный механизму в английском: cannot > can't, I will > I'll, am not > ain't и т. д, или в французском: la > l', de > d'.

Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1):

Нет, подобного явления в русском языке как такового нет. Все гласные всегда произносятся, почти всегда меняют качество в зависимости от положения относительно ударного слога, но никогда не исчезают совсем.

Могу лишь добавить, что русский язык вообще более распевен, гласные иногда даже добавляются для "благозвучия" или фонетической легкости. Правда, около тысячелетия назад произошло явление, называемое "падением редуцированных", из древнерусского исчезли сверхкраткие гласные, но даже это явление совершенно другого порядка.

Answer (score 1):

Есть разве что разговорные упрощения при произнесении некоторых имён в сочетании с отчеством и некоторых слов. В литературных текстах возможна передача таких просторечий.

> Александр Александрович - Сан Саныч
>
> Иванович - Иваныч
>
> Николаевич - Николаич
>
> здравствуйте - здрасте
>
> ваше высокоблагородие - ваше скобородие

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45037/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-ander------).